# flink1.6 streaming non window LEFT OUTER JOIN out of order

Tags: apache-flink

`Streaming non window left outer join` is a new feature in flink1.6. When I do it between two dynamic table. the join result is out of order. How should I use this feature correctly?
The two dynamic table are both order by `data_update_time`. NonWindowJoin left table's state and right tables state both use flink managed state `MapState`. When I view the `non window join` code of flink. I am confused that:
(1) [NonWindowJoin.scala code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OeWZ.png)
the key of `MapState` is `Row` object. The `hashCode` and `equal` function of `Row` is determined by all fields of `Row`. So if the stream events comes from the `binlog` of mysql database, the `MapState[Row, JTuple2[Long, Long]]` will always append(not update). That `MapState` will record the changelog of the same record which in mysql database. I am doubt that whether the order of join result is not determinted?
(2) When iterate it,whether to traverse in the order in which the states are placed?
(3) How should I find the reason of join result out of order.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee regarding the order of the results of a join. Just as in a relational database, Flink's joins produce results in whatever order is convenient and efficient for the implementation. Joins iterate over `MapState` objects, and the specific ordering of those iterators depends on which state backend is being used.

Comment: Appreciate for your answer. I use RocksDB as flink's state backend. I think that  it‘s meaningless for stream processing if the join results is out of order. I don't very undestand the Note in flink's document which about SQL `Outer Equi-join`.
**Note: The order of joins is not optimized. Tables are joined in the order in which they are specified in the FROM clause. Make sure to specify tables in an order that does not yield a cross join (Cartesian product) which are not supported and would cause a query to fail.**
How should I specify the join order in FROM clause?

Comment: For example, can I use `SELECT * FROM Orders LEFT JOIN Product ON Orders.productId = Product.id ORDER BY Orders.data_update_time, Product.data_update_time`.Do you think it's feasible to specify the join order? I am not determinted that it support two sorting fields in From clause.